# How to filter table rows based on a not displayed attribute into span

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datalist

I have a table where each row is an address. Each row has, as well, a zip code but it's hidden.
I need a textbox to filter the address rows **that matches with the zip entered**. The field to search is named as "zip".

Here's my table:

```
<asp:DataList
  id="list1"
  runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <cc1:SWCLabel 
         runat="server"
         Text ='<%# Eval("address")%>'
         zip='<%# Eval("zip")%>'
          />
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Each table rows is rendered like this, note the zip attribute into the span:

```
 <tr>
  <td>
      <span zip="11">address mmomo</span>
  </td>
    </tr>
```

**UPDATED DEMO:**
Here's the demo: The zip textbox matches the zip entirely but I need that matches zips that contains or starts with the text entered:
http://jsfiddle.net/QFQ5k/83/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.expr[':'].containsIgnoreCase = function (n, i, m) {
            return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        };

    var gridAddr = $("#t1");
        var filtroCP = $('#txtbox');
    $("#txtbox").keyup(function () {
            gridAddr .find("tr").hide();
            var data = this.value.split(" ");
            var jo = gridAddr .find("tr");

            if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    jo = jo.filter(function(index){
                        return $(this).find("span").attr("zip").search($("#txtbox").val())!=-1;                  

                    });
                });
                jo.show();
            }
            else {
                jo.show();
            }
        });​
```

**Update**
If you're sure that any one of the child elements of the row contains the attribute "zip" then use this to filter the rows regardless of their rendering:

instead of

`return $(this).find("span").attr("zip").search($("#txtbox").val())!=-1;`

write

`return $(this).find("[zip*='"+$("#txtbox").val()+"']").length>0;`

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/QFQ5k/89/

Comment: This is almost what I need. But I need to get the rows which zips **contain** the entered text, or starts with, not that matches exactly.

Comment: Does not match anything. Better before.

Comment: Yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/QFQ5k/82/ :)  Make sure you're not copying the code wrong

Comment: Thank you. Solved. However, is any way to filter like this without know how are the table rows rendered?

Comment: How would you know what you're looking for then? At least, you have to know that some of the elements in the row contains the "zip" attribute

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use linq.js http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.linq.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr><td zip="112233">112233</td></tr>
<tr><td zip="232323">232323</td></tr>
<tr><td zip="454567">454567</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="filter">
<script>  
$('#filter').change(function(){
    $("[zip]").show();
    $("[zip]").toEnumerable()
    .Select( function(x){  return x.attr('zip').indexOf($('#filter').val())==-1 ? x : null})
    .TojQuery()
    .each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```